# dont make functions within a loop jshint

Tags: javascript

```
for (var p = 0; p < tokiyoPoints.length; p++) { //for loop
        var tpoint = new google.maps.Marker({ //MAP MARKER
            map: map, //MAP BY ID
            //MARKER DROP
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            venue: tokiyoPoints[p].pointId, //FOR LIKES AND RATING
            title: tokiyoPoints[p].pointName, //TITLE OF POINT
            show: ko.observable(true), //SHOW POINT
            selected: ko.observable(false), //SELECT POINT
            position: { //POINT POSITION
                lat: tokiyoPoints[p].pointLat,
                lng: tokiyoPoints[p].pointLng
            }
        });
        tokiyo.push(tpoint); //ADD POINT AT THE END
        tpoint.addListener('click', function() {
            //CLICK ON THE POINTER
            pointerInfo(this, tokyoInfo);
        });
        tpoint.addListener('click', function() {
            //CLICK ON THE POINTER
            BOUNCE(this);
        });

    tpoint.addListener('mouseover', function() {
            //MOSEOVER ON POINT
            this.setIcon(nIcon);
        });
        tpoint.addListener('mouseout', function() {
            //MOUSEOUT FROM THE POINTER
            this.setIcon(uIcon);
        });
    }
```

It gives error-

> Dont make functions inside loop js

Comment: it may be an error, but the code should be OK ... declare the functions as named functions outside the for loop, alternatively, use `tokiyoPoints.forEach` to avoid the issue

Comment: Jaromanda X could you plz give me a detailed solution rather than this?

Comment: Indeed. I posted the comment because you wouldn't believe the number of people that just have to have the solution vaguely described to them before they can work it out for themselves - I would post an answer, but it's been done by someone with a lower expectation

Comment: @JaromandaX Apologies if answer was not the right action for this question. I just thought its better to explain. If there is anything missing, please point it out. And if you wish to answer, I'll remove mine as duplicating would not help anyone. Also I lost you on `lower expectation`.

Comment: @Rajesh - it's all good, your answer is exactly right, my comment was not aimed at you - the `lower expectation` is not meant to be at all an insult to anyone - I posted the first comment because some people figure it out for themselves if given a nudge

Comment: @JaromandaX I did not find it insulting. I understood that by expectation, you meant *effort invested by someone on a problem*. What I didn't was *should we have high expectation from everyone*? Considering OP's rep, he might be new and would not have enough knowledge which resulted in problem. Under such situation, I guess we should explain the **Why**. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The reason its throwing error is because you are creating functions (*event handlers*) in loop.

So if you have say 100 points, you will create 400 functions, but their structure would remain same. Right way to avoid this is to have a named function outside loop and pass reference of these functions to events.

```js
for (var p = 0; p < tokiyoPoints.length; p++) { //for loop
  var tpoint = new google.maps.Marker({ //MAP MARKER
    map: map, //MAP BY ID
    //MARKER DROP
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    venue: tokiyoPoints[p].pointId, //FOR LIKES AND RATING
    title: tokiyoPoints[p].pointName, //TITLE OF POINT
    show: ko.observable(true), //SHOW POINT
    selected: ko.observable(false), //SELECT POINT
    position: { //POINT POSITION
      lat: tokiyoPoints[p].pointLat,
      lng: tokiyoPoints[p].pointLng
    }
  });
  tokiyo.push(tpoint); //ADD POINT AT THE END
  tpoint.addListener('click', clickHandler1);
  tpoint.addListener('click', clickHandler2);

  tpoint.addListener('mouseover', mouseOverHandler);
  tpoint.addListener('mouseout', mouseOutHandler);
}

function clickHandler1() {
  //CLICK ON THE POINTER
  pointerInfo(this, tokyoInfo);
}

function clickHandler2() {
  //CLICK ON THE POINTER
  BOUNCE(this);
}

function mouseOverHandler() {
  //MOSEOVER ON POINT
  this.setIcon(nIcon);
}

function mouseOutHandler() {
  //MOUSEOUT FROM THE POINTER
  this.setIcon(uIcon);
}
```